# add a C++ delegate to C# event

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm accually writing a clr app, and I've got a problem. I have got in C# dll with

```
public event EventHandler SampleHandler;
```

And from C++ I want to add a delegate, but I cant figure it how to do that, in C# it is very simple:

```
  MyC#Class.SampleHandler += delegate(Object o, EventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Some info", "Some more info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
  };
```

But how to achive same resut from C++?

Comment: delegate void MyCliHandler(Object^ o, EventArgs^ e)
{
MessageBox::Show("Some info", "Some more info", MessageBoxButton::OK);
}

Comment: It does not seem to work. I forgot to say, that I'm not using c++11.

Comment: Actually, it's not C++. It's C++/CLI. We should clarify this. Don't you want to add a delegate to C# event?

Comment: I want to add a delegate from C++/CLI program to C# event.

Comment: Create a method on your ref class.
void MyCliHandler(Object^ o, EventArgs^ e) { MessageBox::Show("Some info", "Some more info", MessageBoxButton::OK); } 

Then, add your delegate on your ref class as following;

SampleHandler += gcnew EventHandler(this, &YourRefClass::MyCliHandler);

I tried and worked on me.